# Finding Rank of the following Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> The rank of a $3\times3$ matrix $C=AB$, found by multiplying a non-zero column matrix $A$ of size $3\times1$ and a non-zero row matrix $B$ of size $1\times3$ is **__**.

I don't know the correct answer to this question . Since $A$ and $B$ are non-zero and when we
multiply $A$ and $B$ we get a $3\times3$ matrix . So I feel rank is $3$ . Is this right?

Comment: are you sure that you know the definition of rank?

Comment: No.  That's not correct.  Any other ideas?  What's the definition of rank?

Comment: If the rank is 3, then $\det(AB) \neq 0$. But this cannot be true in general; see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935319/shortest-and-most-elementary-proof-that-the-product-of-an-n-column-and-an-n

Comment: You don't need anything fancy to solve this. Just write $A=\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3\end{bmatrix}^T$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix} b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \end{bmatrix}$, compute $AB$ explicitly and use your hypothesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\det\left(\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}(x\;y\;z)\right)=\begin{vmatrix}ax&ay&az\\bx&by&bz\\cx&cy&cz\end{vmatrix}=abc\begin{vmatrix}x&y&z\\x&y&z\\x&y&z\end{vmatrix}=0$$

so the rank is *always* less than three

Comment: The known property $\text{rank}\left(MN\right)\leq \min\left(\text{rank}(M),\text{rank}(N)\right)$ yields a much tighter bound.

Comment: Indeed so, yet I seem to have applied your comment idea. Yet from the above is also clear the rank cannot be greater than one

Comment: Okay i get it now . It is not three . But is it 1 or 2 ?

Comment: Read both comments above **and** the answer itself, @jayagopijayamani .

Comment: @jayagopijayamani No.  Look at Omnomnomnom's hint.

Comment: Okay . The answer is 1

Comment: Indeed it is, @jayagopijayamani

Comment: @jayagopijayamani But do you see why?

Comment: Yes . First Determinant of AB is 0 .Which confirms it is not 3.Then A is 1*3 .   And Rank(A)=min(1,3) which is 1, and the same for Rank(B)=1 . rank(AB)<=min(rank(A),rank(B)). rank(AB)=min(1,1) which is 1 . @ Bye_World

Comment: @jayagopijayamani If you're going to go on in Maths it's generally better if you don't just memorize formulas (at least until you've proven them yourself once or twice).  So I wouldn't recommend that you just memorize (or even just trust us that) rank(AB) $\le$ min(rank(A), rank(B)), even though it is true.  I think a much better way to solve this at the introductory level is to notice that each row of AB (see above) is a scalar multiple of $[x,y,z]$, and thus the row rank is at most 1 (and similarly column rank is at most 1).  And thus the rank is at most 1.

Comment: @jayagopijayamani Your argument is incorrect. You can only conclude $\text{rank}(AB)\leq 1$.

Comment: @GitGud, he already wrote both vectors are nonzero. This already gives $\;\text{rank}(AB)=1\;$

Comment: Pardon me, I'm sure I'm completely missing the point of this answer, but why is the abc matrix a row and xyz a column? Should it not be the other way around, given the original question (`3x1 . 1x3`)?

Comment: @mafutrct, you're completely right. Thanks, the answer's been edited.

Comment: Ah, cool :) The closing bracket should probably include the second matrix now though. (Sorry that I can't fix that one myself, I still can't figure out the latex for matrices.)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** compute the product $AB$, and notice that each row (or column) is a multiple of some non-zero row (if any are non-zero).

Answer (score 1):

Matrix of the form

$A=vw^T$
$(v,w\neq 0)$

is always of rank one. It's easy to see from svd (Singular Value Decomposition).

Answer (score 1):

The rank of a product of a $n\times k$ and a $k\times m$ matrix cannot exceed any one of $n,k,m$. Here $(n,k,m)=(3,1,3)$ so the rank is at most$~1$. You need to worry about the possibility that the result is zero, in which case the rank will be zero. However for $k=1$ each combination of an entry of $A$ and an entry of $B$ produces a separate entry of $AB$, so the result will only be zero if one of $A$ and $B$ is, which is not the case.